# std::basic_ostream is inaccessible in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I get the following error and I'm not sure what the issue is

> 1 IntelliSense: "std::basic_ostream<_Elem,
>   _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared
>   at line 82 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\VC\include\ostream") is inaccessible

**Book.cpp**

```
ostream operator<< (ostream& out, const Book & b){
    out << "Title: " << b.my_Title << endl;
    out << "Author: " << b.my_Author << endl;
    out << "Number of time checkout out: " << b.my_NumberOfTimesCheckedOut;
    return(out);
}
```

I get the issue with the `return(out);`

**Book.h**

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace CS20A
{
    class Book {
    public:
        Book();
        Book( string author, string title );
        string getTitle() const;
        string getAuthor() const;
        int getNumberOfTimesCheckedOut() const;
        void increaseNumberOfTimesCheckedOut( int amount=1 );
        friend ostream operator<< ( ostream& out, const Book & b );
    private:
        string my_Author;
        string my_Title;
        int my_NumberOfTimesCheckedOut;
    };
};
#endif
```

I don't even understand what the error is telling me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're using an ancient compiler that implements a prohibition on copying `std::ostream`, which is not copyable, by making its copy-constructor private; hence the confusing "inaccessible" error.

`std::ostream` is not copyable. You must return a reference:

```
ostream &operator<< (ostream& out, const Book & b){
```

Comment: But now I get an error on `friend ostream operator<< ( ostream& out, const Book & b );` saying > IntelliSense: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Comment: I'm getting a lot of more random errors. But you fixed my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to return a reference of ostream.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Book & b){
    out << "Title: " << b.my_Title << endl;
    out << "Author: " << b.my_Author << endl;
    out << "Number of time checkout out: " << b.my_NumberOfTimesCheckedOut;
    return(out);
}
```

Even Better, you get to_string method like Java in new C++ versions.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my error but now I have a new one =/

Error 5 error C2556: 'std::ostream &CS20A::operator <<(std::ostream &,const CS20A::Book &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'std::ostream CS20A::operator <<(std::ostream &,const CS20A::Book &)'

Comment: You need to add reference in your class declaration also - friend ostream& operator<< ( ostream& out, const Book & b );